# Is there a way to export Power Pivot Data Model to Power Query?

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot, powerquery

I have a power pivot data model of around 20000 rows only and wish to take that data over power query window for further modification. What i'm doing right now is , go to Power Pivot Manage Data Model window and then Copy the data, paste it as normal CSV format and run over power query there. I'm looking forward to an easy way to link between power pivot model and power query, so I could just Refresh All and thereby both models will update without any manual copy/paste work. I have checked all through Google and various websites however all I could find was either copy and paste the data (that I'm doing right now) or a vba (however I couldn't figure out how that works, but it does ideally is a copy paste only to normal spread sheet. Please advice.

Comment: How did you get the data into Power Pivot?

Comment: @RADO From the same excel, total of 10 tables in separate 10 sheets. 1 main table and the other 9 sheets are linked to the main via the "RELATED" dax formula within the power pivot model. I just need this data model to a power query window, so I could Group By and Unpivot/Pivot data stuff

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the data is first added from the sheets to the PowerPivot model, and then you want to export the same data into PowerQuery?

Comment: @RADO exactly. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to load the data from the sheets into PowerQuery first, then do your modifications, and then load the modified data from PowerQuery into Power Pivot?

Comment: No, I just straight away imported the table to Power Pivot. I can do whatever you propose to make this happen. will modifying first on PowerQuery window and to PowerPivot enables me the possibility to get the connectivity back to PowerQuery again?